# Access to CPU registers in GMM space

Tags: firmware, hardware, register

AMD's BIOS and Kernel Developer’s Guide (BKDG) documents GMM registers and access to them:

> GMMxXXXXX: GPU memory mapped registers; XXXXX specifies the hexadecimal byte address offset (this may be 2 to 5 digits) from the base address register; The base address for this space is specified by D1F0x18 [Graphics Memory Mapped Registers Base Address].

`D1F0x18` has the following structure (I also add a column with values that I get):

| Bits | My value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31:18 | 0x3c08 | BaseAddr[31:18]: base address. |
| 17:16 | 0 | BaseAddr[17:16]: base address. |
| 15:4 | 0 | BaseAddr[15:4]: base address. |
| 3 | 0 | prefetchable. 0=Non-prefetchable memory region. |
| 2:1 | 0 | base address register type. 00b=32-bit BAR. 10b=64-bit BAR. |
| 0 | 0 | memory space type. 0=Memory mapped base address. |

How to properly access registers in the GMM space?

There are three base address fields in the `D1F0x18` register, and the guide doesn't explain any further how to compile the base address. I tried to read memory (in Linux with `root` privileges) at the following memory offsets, but all of them return me `Segmentation fault` error.

```
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0x3c08); // Base address itself
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0x4378); // 0x3c08+0x770 (GMMx770)
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0x4381); // 0x3c08+0x770+3

printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0x3c080000); // Base address appended with zeroes
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0x3c080770); // plus GMMx770 offset
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0x3c080773); // plus size of the GMMx770

printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0xf0200000); // 0x3c08 shifted left by 2 bits (so that to align 31:18 field to 16 bits)
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0xf0200770); // plus GMMx770 offset
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned)*(unsigned char*)0xf0200773); // plus size GMMx770 offset
```

#### Edit

There is a source code of the [Coreboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreboot) project available on the Internet. <s>There are clear footprints that they implement access to the GMM space, but I couldn't extract the method from their code either.</s> The code gives some clues:

1. <s>It looks, like they use the base address as is, i.e. it is `0x3c080000` in my case.</s>
2. They set bits 0 and 1 in `D1F0x04` so that apparently to enable access to the device's memory area (I have both of these bits set by default).
3. They read memory with `__readfsdword`. Because I am on GCC, I redefined this function as follows, but still get the `Segmentation fault`:

```
unsigned long __readfsdword(const unsigned long Offset)
{
    unsigned long value;
    __asm__ __volatile__("movl %%fs:%a[Offset], %k[value]" : [value] "=r" (value) : [Offset] "ir" (Offset));
    return value;
}
```